# Is paths interpretation on mono on mac different from the .net windows version?

Tags: c#, macos, mono, path-separator

I'm translating an app from .net on windows to mono on mac. I found an error that was happening, that I think related with how the backslash is interpreted on mono - mac.

```
Path.GetDirectoryName("Assembly\\file.dll")
```

On mono for mac that return an empty string, on .net windows that return "Assembly". Is that the normal behaviour? can I change the way path are interpreted with some kind of configuration, or I need to replace every backslash with forwardslash?

Comment: You likely need to use platform-specific delimiters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @xxbbcc apparently you are right. The problem arise using the library SharpZipLib. The object ZipEntry create their paths only with backslash non taking in account what operating system is running. I think I'll process those paths using as a replacement the value of Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.

Comment: Various libraries for .NET may not have been written for platforms other than Windows - I don't know specifically about SharpZipLib but if a library hardcodes a specific separator, it may have all kinds of file system issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on mono you can use `MONO_IOMAP` environment variable to ignore differences like path ( windows is case insensitive, unix is case sensitive) and path separator ( '\' vs '/' )

see http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/iomap/

the best long term solution anyway is to use methods like `Path.Combine` or `Path.DirectorySeparator` to fix these problems